Looking for the fastest high/arbitrary precision integer/floating point arithmetic library for C++ that provides support for trigonometric functions
I am performing arithmetic computations with complex numbers that are generated from values that are currently pushing the numeric limits of standard C++. Thus, I am looking for the fastest high/arbitrary precision integer/floating point arithmetic library for C++ that provides support for trigonometric functions and complex numbers in the sense that you can use the said functions/structures with the extended integer/floating point structures that the library provides. I was led to believe that the GMP library: https://gmplib.org/ is an extremely fast choice for arbitrary precision arithmetic, but as I am reading through the manual it is unclear to me whether I can use trigonometric functions/complex numbers with the extended arithmetic structures of the library. Some other sources mentioned the GNU MPC library: https://www.multiprecision.org/, but I have no idea how that fares to GMP or any other high/arbitrary precision arithmetic library.
